# In Plasmic, how can I control a slider with custom buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I'm building a demo website page in Plasmic as a sort of proof of concept. The design I have been given includes a slider with custom SVG buttons outside of the slider. I've created the slider itself with the default Plasmic widget and of course, I have created the buttons.

However, what I don't know how to do is link the default slider widget to the buttons I have created, such that the buttons control the slider. Is there a way to do that. Unfortunately, I don't have any code to show you, as I really don't know where to start on this.

The only idea I had is to create a completely custom slider with CSS & JS, like this one on CodePen:

https://codepen.io/MijeongLee/pen/bGGqPWo

```
<h1>Simple slide show</h1>
<div class="custom-slider">
  <div class="custom-box">1</div> 
  <div class="custom-box">2</div> 
  <div class="custom-box">3</div> 
  <div class="custom-box">4</div> 
  <div class="custom-box">5</div> 
  <div class="custom-box">6</div> 
  <div class="custom-box">7</div> 
  <div class="custom-box">8</div> 
  <div class="custom-box">9</div> 
</div>

body{
  font-family: Lato;
  font-weight: 600;
}
h1{
  padding-left: 120px;
  color: #043e46;
  font-size: 2.2em;
}
.custom-slider{
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}
.custom-box{
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align:center;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px gray;
  margin: 15px;
  font-size: 5em;
  padding: 50px;
}
.slick-prev, .slick-next{
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  color: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #043e46;
}
.slick-slider{
  user-select: none;
}
.slick-next{
  right: -30px;
}
.slick-prev{
  left: -30px;
}
.slick-next:before{
  content: '\003e';
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 1000;
  padding-left: 12px;
  color: white;
}
.slick-prev:before{
  content: '\003c';
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 1000;
  padding-left: 9px;
  color: white;
}

$('.custom-slider').slick({
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 2000,
 responsive: [
    {
        breakpoint: 1200,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 3,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
          infinite: true,
          dots: false
        }
      },
    {
        breakpoint: 900,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 2,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
          infinite: true,
          dots: false
        }
      },
    {
        breakpoint: 550,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
          infinite: true,
          dots: false
        }
      }
    ]
});
```

This just isn't as user-friendly for non-developers to update. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thank you!